# Flutter - How to change itemCount depending on JSON data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `GridView` which forms groups of 6 elements that keep incrementing their index value and adds a `Divider` after every 6 elements

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, int) {
        return Divider(color: Colors.black,);
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemBuilderIndex) {
        return GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 2.0,
          children: List.generate(6, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Text(
                  '${(itemBuilderIndex * 6) + index} AM',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
      itemCount: feed.length, //Here is where the problem lies
    ));
  }
```

My `feed.length` is a variable value that gets fetched from `JSON`.
The problem is, if my `feed.length` = 12, then my grid shows 12 rows with groups of 6 elements even though I am supposed to only have 2 rows that will satisfy 12 elements.
[image: Preview of my current GridView]

Comment: @Er1 could you please give this a look